# Laravel Inertia React not passing any props

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I'm trying to figure out my issue with passing props to a react component. The project is completely stock (Laravel 9.19, standard Inertia installation).

The problem is I do not receive any props when I check my React DevTools in Chrome, it just contains the standard *errors: {}* property. Does anyone see my issue or can teach me how to  pass props with inertia? (I just need to understand how to pass this example 'name' variable)

This is my web.php file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Models\Product;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return inertia('Home', [
        'name' => 'testName',
    ]);
})->name('/');
```

app.jsx file:

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createInertiaApp, Head } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        return render(<App {...props} />, el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

Home.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '@/Shared/Navbar';
import { Head, usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

const Home = () => {
  const { name } = usePage().props;
    return (
      <>
      <Head>
          <title>Home</title>
          <meta type="description" head-key="description" content="Home"/>
      </Head>
      {name}
      </>
    )
}

Home.layout = page => <Navbar children={page} headTitle={"Home"}/>

export default Home
```

Edit:
HandleInertiaRequests.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Middleware;

class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The root template that's loaded on the first page visit.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup#root-template
     * @var string
     */
    protected $rootView = 'app';

    /**
     * Determines the current asset version.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/asset-versioning
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function version(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return parent::version($request);
    }

    /**
     * Defines the props that are shared by default.
     *
     * @see https://inertiajs.com/shared-data
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function share(Request $request): array
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your ```HandleInertiaRequests``` look like

Comment: It's completely stock, I didn't  change anything

Answer (score 0):

try change `intertia` function by `Inertia::render(...)`

Check if can send props with `Inertia::share('name', '...');` before return view

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, it had nothing to do with Inertia.

I was using route cache, so my changes in the `web.php` file were not applied after saving it.

Fixed it by clearing the route cache with `php artisan cache:clear`